# GCC Doesn't Compile C Codes as Expected in Ubuntu

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu

This morning in my CS lab, I was compiling and executing some C code. The code are as follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 3

int main()
{
float x[SIZE];
float *fp;
int i;

for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
//{
    x[i] = 0.5*(float)i;
//}

for(i-0; i<SIZE; i++)
//{ 
    printf(" %d %f \n", i, x[i]);
    
//}

fp=x;

for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
//{
    printf(" %d %f \n", i, *(fp+i));
//}  
}
```

This is the command I used in Ubuntu terminal to compile:

> gcc -o program program.c

This is the command i used to execute

> ./program

This is the result I encountered:

> 0     0.50000
>
> 1     1.50000
>
> 2     2.50000

This the result I expected and found on other computers in the same lab.

> 0     0.50000
>
> 1     1.50000
>
> 2     2.50000
>
> 0     0.50000
>
> 1     1.50000
>
> 2     2.50000

**Disclaimer:** I double checked and triple checked the my code is entirely intact with ones in the other computers.

Clearly, something is wrong with the compiler here. Can anyone advise me what is the problem? And how to fix it?

Regards

Comment: `for(i-0;`? Anyway, if this is C, why is it tagged C++, not C?

Comment: "Clearly, something is wrong with the compiler here." No, the problem is _very rarely_ the compiler. Assume the problem is in your code and turn up the compiler warning level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
for(i-0; i<SIZE; i++)
   ^^^^^
```

This makes the for-statement have no effect and hence the `printf` that follows gives no output
If you **[compile it with strict warnings](http://ideone.com/TzWVN)** the compiler shall tell you so.

**Output:**

> cc1: warnings being treated as errors
>   prog.c: In function ‘main’:
>   prog.c:15: error: statement with no effect

Once you fix the obvious typo, all **[compilers will generate the output twice](http://ideone.com/RjtJ2)**.